# How to create silverlight 4 usercontrol with dependency property that can accept any type

Tags: silverlight, generics, types, dependencies, properties

I am looking for a way to create an UserControl in silverlight 4 and expose a dependency property, which can accept any type. What I mean by that is, for example, if you look at standard silverlight control like AutoCompleteBox, it is capable of handling any type of collections. So you can bind AutoCompleteBox with `IEnumerable<Human> or IENumerable<Animal>` etc. And when any item is selected AutoCompleteBox returns the selected value either Human instance or Animal instance via SelectedItem dependency property.

I want to achieve similar flexibility with my usercontrol. I wouild like to expose 2 dependency properties SuggestedItems and SelectedItem. Which ever collection is set to SuggestedItems via consumers of this usercontrol thru Binding, lets take as an example `IEnumerable<Car>`, the I want SelectedItem property to send instance of Car type back to consumer thru Binding. If I used `IEnumerable<Boat>`, then I need Boat to be returned with SelectedItem.

I was trying to achieve it by using below example using MVVM, but its not working. I am looking for some clues as to how it should be designed, Am I even on a correct path or I have to completely alter my design?

I created an UserControl called VehicleSelectorUserControl which has its own dedicated ViewModel called VehicleSelectorViewModel with two proerties SuggestedItems, SelectedItem.

And usercontrol has corresponding Dependency properties in its codebehind to expose them to consumers of usercontrol. UserControl XAML has a ListBox which is bound to SuggestedItems property of VehicleSelectorViewModel. When user makes a selection, VehicleSelectorViewModel SelectedItem is set, which them invokes a delegate called ItemSelected to notify VehicleSelectorUserControl codebehind, which then sets the SelectedItem Dependency property to make it available to consumer.

Below is code from the VehicleSelectorUserControl.xaml.cs code behind.

```
private VehicleSelectorViewModel _TheViewModel;
    public UserNameControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _TheViewModel = Resources["TheViewModel"] as VehicleSelectorViewModel;
        _TheViewModel.ItemSelected = OnItemSelected;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> SuggestedItems
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(SuggestedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SuggestedItemsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SuggestedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SuggestedItems", typeof(IEnumerable<object>), typeof(VehicleSelectorControl), new PropertyMetadata(OnSuggestedItemsSet));

    private static void OnSuggestedItemsSet(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _TheViewModel.SuggestedItems = e.NewValue;
    }

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (String) GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(VehicleSelectorControl), null);

    private void OnItemSelected()
    {
        SelectedItem = _TheViewModel.SelectedItem;
    }
```

Its ViewModel VehicleSelectorViewModel code

```
public Action ItemSelected { get; set; }

    private dynamic _SelectedItem;

    public dynamic SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _SelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _SelectedItem)
            {
                _SelectedItem = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
                if(ItemSelected != null) ItemSelected.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }


    private dynamic _SuggestedItems;

    public dynamic SuggestedItems
    {
        get { return _SuggestedItems; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _SuggestedItems)
            {
                _SuggestedItems = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SuggestedItems");
            }
        }
    }
```

The XAML of consumer will look like (Consumer has its own ViewModel, which responsible for supplying SuggestedCars [`IEnumerable<Car>`], SuggestedBoats [`IEnumerable<Boat>`].

```
            <my:VehicleSelectorControl x:Name="MyCarSelectorControl" 
                                   SuggestedItems="{Binding SuggestedCars, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                                   SelectedItem="{Binding UserSelectedCar, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <my:VehicleSelectorControl x:Name="MyBoatSelectorControl" 
                                   SuggestedItems="{Binding SuggestedBoats, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                                   SelectedItem="{Binding UserSelectedBoat, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: I would use just the `IEnumerable` class without any generic parameters. Also the `dynamic` keyword is unnecessary here. Use real types in the view model and objects in the control, the xaml will do the rest of the work to convert values.

Comment: In that case, I have to explicitly do type casting. I am trying to preserve types with IEnumerable<T> and want to make the UserControl be more generic. Instead of usercontrol, I am going to try custom control with TemplateBinding and see if its going to help me achieve what i want.